# Simulate request scope in non-Web code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, static, singleton

**Background:** I need parts of my system to be able to push various status messages to some data structure so that they can be consumed by a caller, without passing the data structure into methods explicitly, and where the needs of the callers can differ.

**Detail:** my application has two (and conceivably more) heads, an ASP.NET MVC 5 web site and a Windows service. So normally, while the composition root of a web application would be the web site itself, I am using a separate composition root that both these "front ends" connect to--this allows them to share a common configuration, as almost all of their dependency injection will be 100% identical. Plus, for testing, I've decided to keep most of the code out of the web site as truly unit testing controllers is problematic.

So my code needs to be able to run outside of the context of any web request. Similarly, anything the service does on a schedule needs to be able to be run as an on-demand job from the web site. So most of the heavy-lifting code in my application is NOT in the web site or the service.

Now, back to the needs of my status messages:

1. Some status messages will be logged, but potentially more will be logged when run as a service. It's okay to queue the log items and save them at the end.
2. When, say, a job is run on-demand from the web site, fewer things may be logged because any issues the user can take care of will be displayed directly to the user, and for debug purposes we only care about outright errors happening. New messages need to be pushed to the web site immediately (probably through websockets).
3. Also, a job may be run in debug or verbose mode, so that more informational or warning messages are produced one time (say on the web) than would be the case another time (from the headless service). Code generating messages shouldn't worry about these details at all, unless something that would hurt performance in production is placed inside compiler directives for debug mode).
4. Additionally, some of the code pushes errors, warnings, or information into the objects that are returned from a request. These are easy to handle. But other errors, warnings, or information (such as errors that prevent said requested objects from being fetched at all) need to bubble up outside of the normal return values.

Right now I'm using something that seems less than ideal: all my methods have to accept a parameter that they can modify in order to bubble up such errors. For example:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<UsableItem> GetUsableItems(
   ReadOnlyHashSet<string> itemIds,
   List<StatusMessage> statusMessages
) {
    var resultItems = _itemService.Get(itemIds);
    var resultItemsByHasFrobDuplicate = resultItems
       .GroupBy(i => i.FrobId)
       .ToLookup(grp => grp.Count() > 1, grp => grp.ToList());
    statusMessages
       .AddRange(
          resultItemsByHasFrobDuplicate[true]
             .Select(items => $@"{items[0].FrobId
                } is used by multiple items {string.Join(",", items.Select(i => i.usableItemId))
                }")
       );
    return resultItemsByHasFrobDuplicate[false]
       .Select(grp => grp.First())
       .ToList()
       .AsReadOnly();
 }
```

So you can see here that while normally items can be in the return value from the method (and these items can even have their own status messages placed on them), others cannot—the calling code can't deal with duplicates and expects a collection of `UsableItem` objects that do NOT have duplicate `FrobId` values. The situation of the duplicates is unexpected and needs to bubble up to the user or the log.

The code would be greatly improved by being able to remove the `statusMessages` parameter and do something more like `CurrentScope.PushMessage(message)` and know that these messages will be properly handled based on their severity or other rules (the real messages are an object with several properties).

Oh, and I left something out in the code above. What I really have to do is:

```
_itemService.Get(itemIds, statusMessages); // -- take the darn parameter everywhere
```

Argh. That is not ideal.

I instantly thought of `MiniProfiler.Current` as similar, where it's available anywhere but it's scoped to the current request. But I don't understand how it is able to be static, yet segregate any `Step` calls between different requests so that a user doesn't get another user's steps in his output. Plus, doesn't it only work for MVC? I need this to work when there is no MVC, just non-web code.

Can anyone suggest a way to improve my code and not have to pass around a list to method after method? Something that will work with unit tests is also important, as I need to be able to set up a means to capture the bubbled errors in my mock within a unit test (or be able to do nothing at all if that's not the desired portion of the system to test).

P.S. I don't mind tactful criticism of my little `ToLookup` pattern above for separating duplicates. I use that technique a lot and would be interested in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking at this the wrong way. None of this actually involves or really is related to a request. You simply need some service you can inject which pushes messages out. *How* it does that is inconsequential, and the whole point of dependency injection is that the class with the dependency shouldn't know or care.

Create an interface for your messaging service:

```
public interface IMessagingService
{
    void PushMessage(string message);
}
```

Then, you should alter your class which contains `GetUsableItems` a bit to inject the messaging service into the constructor. In general, method injection (what you're doing currently by passing `List<StatusMessages>` into the method) is frowned upon.

```
public class MyAwesomeClass
{
    protected readonly IMessagingService messenger;

    public MyAwesomeClass(IMessagingService messenger)
    {
        this.messenger = messenger;
    }
```

Then, in your method:

```
messenger.PushMessage("My awesome message");
```

The implementation of this interface, then will probably vary based on whether it's injected in the web app or the windows service. Your web app will likely have an implementation that simply utilizes its own code to push messages, whereas the windows service will likely need an implementation that utilizes `HttpClient` to make requests to your web app. Setup your DI container to inject the right implementation for the right application and you're done.

Comment: This seems reasonable and at least lets me move the object-passing to the containing class of my methods, though I might have to move a few dependencies from static scope to request scope (not a big deal). However, my project has several parts and pieces that mean I have a fair number of classes to inject the service to. I agree this is superior to what I have and I'll probably do that (kind of a head-smack moment here), but I'd still love some way to use a "global" that isn't really global.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I just instinctually felt that method injection was bad, but I just wasn't seeing the better way. Now that you say it, it's kind of obvious... I have no one to give me an substantive code review here... sigh.

Comment: Well, your service here would likely be "global" in the context of the application. You'd inject it with a Singleton/Request scope. The service will worry about persisting your messages some how, such that they are available to all applications.